# How to use apply_filter() for Jetpack Lazyload

Tags: php, wordpress, lazy-loading

I am using Jetpack Lazyload on my Website. I have an online store using WooCommerce.

The jetpack Lazyload feature works great. The only problem I am having (which is a pretty big one) is that when I select a product to view, the product page opens but the main product image is covered by the thumbnails.

If the product has multiple images, I can select a thumbnail and it sorts itself, however if there is only one image then it is stuck like that.

I found [this](https://developer.jetpack.com/hooks/lazyload_is_enabled/) :

```
apply_filters( 'lazyload_is_enabled', bool true )
```

but when I try to add this to functions.php, visual studio code recognises it as an error. I tried uploading anyway and it broke my site.

I have never used this function. If someone has experience using it and could help me implement it properly, that would be great.

thanks

Comment: Should be just `apply_filters( 'lazyload_is_enabled', true )` since bool just defines the type of variable

Comment: @Tristan thanks for reply, I should have noticed that lol. Does it go into functions.php?

Comment: Yes, hooks and filters should go in functions.php

Answer (score 0):

You can just call it like this if you want to enable image lazy loading:

```
apply_filters( 'lazyload_is_enabled', true );
```

Or, if you want to disable image lazy loading for the non-Mobile UI:

```
function isMobileDevice() {
    return preg_match("/(android|avantgo|blackberry|bolt|boost|cricket|docomo|fone|hiptop|mini|mobi|palm|phone|pie|tablet|up\.browser|up\.link|webos|wos)/i", $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
}

if(!isMobileDevice()){
    apply_filters ( 'lazyload_is_enabled', false );
}
```